# Getting a command from a command block to tp me if my score is min and near coordinates to different coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want a command that does `tp @p`with the args:

-a certain coord location
-with a decent radius near it
-only if the score of Death is at least 1
----teleports you to different coordinates

Here is what I tried:

```
/tp @p [x=359,y=64,z=769,r=10,score_Death_min=01]x=-252,y=105,z=697
```

Any idea what I need to fix?

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you Ben?

Answer (score 2):

It's simply formatted incorrectly. The correct command would be:

```
/tp @p[x=359,y=64,z=769,r=10,score_Death_min=1] 252 105 697
```

(No space between @p and [, no x= etc, 1 instead of 01)

Be sure to note that if this command is activated when someone dies, their dead body will be teleported to the coordinates "252 105 697" and when they respawn, they will spawn at their spawnpoint. Consider using the same command except with /spawnpoint to fix this.